# How to resize the horizontal menu with respect to its li?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 7 menus in my code.Sometimes it may be 6 based on the usertype.If admin is entered it will be 7.User may have only 6 menus.
How can resize the menu dynamically.
For that I used the code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">home7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I do this with jquery?

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('#menu ul li').length > 6 ) {
        $('#menu ul li').css('width','14.5%'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu ul li').css('width','16.6%'); 
    }
});
    }
});
```

Comment: to be clear: you want the above to appear in one row that takes up the full width?

Comment: We need to see your css, depending on how its styled, it will resize without needing jquery.

Comment: An alternative will be to center the menu with auto margin. But, if you really need to resize the menu then, use Jquery, it's simple. 
First, create two different classes with different width for your li.
class1:.li_7 
class2:.li_6
Then, you will have to count the number of li that you have in your menu. 
If you have 6 li, add the class li_6 else li_7
Then,

Comment: @hexblot-actually I want to resize the menu with respect to li.the ul is 100%.

Comment: You probably have your li as block or inline-block. If you do, and you use percentage to define the width of the li's, that will do as long as the container (ul) has a fixed width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the desired outcome is for the above menu to be rendered in one line, regardless of the exact number of items -

the best way to do this would be with tables, as they have native behavior for this type of thing ( taking up a long line and distributing items evenly over it ). The good thing is that we can easily fake that behavior using

```
#menu { display: table; width: 100%; }
#menu ul { display: table-row; }
#menu ul li { display: table-cell; }
```

this will automatically distribute your `<li>`s over a long line, using the containers width.

You can also see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxG82/) with an example of the above.

Comment: Good answer, although don't say "with tables", as that gives the wrong idea. This answer does not use tables, but CSS `display: table`, which is quite different, and much more appropriate. :-)

Comment: if i have 6 menu.is it take the full width?

Comment: @Agent1 Look at the JSFiddle he linked to and try adding or removing some list items.

Comment: @ralph.m: I meant that we're imitating table behavior, and Agent1: it will take full width for any number of items, as long as they actually fit

Comment: @Agent1: with the above code, you do not need to set a width. It is auto-set by CSS (remove related JS code entirely). Is it a requirement to have that width?

Comment: @hexblot-u der? I have little doubt

Comment: @Agent1: please remove your jQuery code, CSS as shown above will always (regardless of number of items) distribute items in one row.

Comment: i used the jquery because I have lot of style to apply for this menu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming hexblot's answer isn't what you wanted and you want to distribute LI's of a varying width across the width of a container element, without the LI's necessarily taking up the full-width of your navigation bar then use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sxGMZ/

```
#menu ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: brown;
}

#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 12px 0 12px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of table cells use display inline-block:

```
#menu { display: inline-block;background:#000; }
#menu ul { display: inline-block; margin:0;padding: 0; }
#menu ul li { display: inline-block; margin:0; padding: 0;}
#menu ul li a { display: inline-block; padding: 10px; color: #fff;}
#menu ul li a:hover { color: #ff0;}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BtvY9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BtvY9/1/

Add a larger width than the li's then suddenly this breaks if hexblot interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: this approach will keep all your menu items to the left, instead of evenly distributing them as in my answer. You can easily use whichever  is preferable as a behavior.

Comment: I want to check the menu in jquery.If it has 6 menus.It must take the full width